# How to write unit test which creates new thread

Tags: java, multithreading, junit, mockito

I have following method for test:

```
public class classToTest{
    @Autowired
    private Alternator alternator;

     public void methodToTest(){
         Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {
             public void run() {
                 while(true) {
                     if(alternator.get()) {
                         System.out.print("Hello");
                         alternator.set(false);
                     }
                 }
             }
          };
          t.start()
    }
}
```

I need to check that was invoked method

```
alternator.set(false);
```

How can I do it?

Comment: What *is* `alternator`? How is it created in the code to be tested?

Comment: Lets say that **alternator** is external service

Comment: That does not help. Does it implement an interface? Is it created using `new` or do you use some form of DI?

Comment: We need to know `alternator` because you are probably going to have to mock it to test this.  Hence "service" is just a bit too vague.

Comment: I have updated topic. Is it enough?

Comment: You've tagged your question `mockito`. Did you try to mock `alternator`?

Comment: Problem with **concurrency** I am not sure that method will invoke before verification

Answer (score 0):

Instead of starting a thread directly, can you pass in an "Executor" instance?

For example...

```
public class ClassToTest{
    @Autowired
    private Alternator alternator;

    @Autowired @Qualifier("myExecutor")
    private java.util.concurrent.Executor executor;

    public void methodToTest() {
        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
               while(true) {
                 if(alternator.get()) {
                     System.out.print("Hello");
                     alternator.set(false);
                 }
             }
        };

        executor.execute(runnable);
    }
}
```

Now you can test this easier...

```
public class ClassToTestTest {

    ...

    @Before
    public void setup() {
        alternator = mock(Alternator.class);
        executor = mock(Executor.class);

        obj = new ClassToTest();
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(obj, "alternator", alternator);
        ReflectionTestUtils.setField(obj, "executor", executor);
    }

    @Test
    public void shouldStartRunnable() {
        obj.methodToTest();

        ArgumentCaptor<Runnable> runnableCaptor = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Runnable.class);

        verify(executor).execute(runnableCaptor.capture());

        Runnable runnable = runnableCaptor.getValue();

        // Now test your actual "runnable"...
        when(alternator.get()).thenReturn(true);
        runnable.run();

        verify(alternator).set(false);
    }
}
```

(Have not tried to compile this, so I apologise if there are any mistakes!!)

Answer (score 0):

Though [Bret's post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28415787/1426891) of passing in an executor is very much recommended, you can use the [`timeout()`](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/1.9.5/org/mockito/Mockito.html#22) mock verification setting to test for asynchronous conditions.

```
verify(alternator, timeout(500)).set(false);
```

Note that this will necessarily increase the flakiness of your test (i.e. the likelihood that the test fails when the code passes). With a sensible timeout value, that flakiness should be negligible, but if you're making this a part of your core test infrastructure you may consider refactoring to allow for synchronous execution in the test.